# Unity instantiate new objects after 1 second of destroying previous

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have problem with code. I can't make that my cube object automatically show new 1 second after destroying previous cube. This is my code:

void OnTriggerEnter (Collider other){

```
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag ("cube1")) { 
        other.gameObject.SetActive (false);
        makenew ();

    }

}

IEnumerator makenew ()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds (1f);
    GameObject cube = Instantiate (cubePrefab) as GameObject;
    gameObject.SetActive (true);

}
```

}

Comment: So you are calling `gameObject.SetActive (true);` to itself? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also do:

```
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag ("cube1")) { 
        other.gameObject.SetActive (false);
        Invoke("makenew", 1.0f);

    }

}

void makenew ()
{

    GameObject cube = Instantiate (cubePrefab) as GameObject;
    gameObject.SetActive (true);

}
```

As I don't know exactly what you are doing, my **doubts** lies here:

The `other.gameObject` is a cube you deactivate. (1st game object)

`GameObject cube` is the new one. (2nd game object)

With this code:  `gameObject.SetActive (true);` you are making the actual 3rd game object (the one that has the script with this code) turns active, what I might guess it *already* is, isn't? What I trying to express is that with this code you are calling the owner of script. Is this alright? Or do you want to activate the "other" old cube like:

`other.gameObject.SetActive (true);` ?

This way you gonna have 2 cubes. The old one (other) and the new one (cube). Just a doubt.

**Edited**: As I suspected the line `gameObject.SetActive(true);` was not OP intent. His prefab was deactivated by default, so the `makenew()` method should be like:

```
void makenew ()
    {

        GameObject cube = Instantiate (cubePrefab) as GameObject;
        cube.SetActive (true);

    }
```

Comment: It works, but my cube is not shown on my screen. 
I see on my hierarchy cube(clone) but it is not black, it is grey.

Comment: your prefab is activated by default? if not put after creating the cube: `cube.SetActive(true);`

Comment: I fix everything. Thank you very much. I change this line     gameObject.SetActive (true);

to

cube.SetActive (true);

And everything is perfect.

Comment: Great. I will updated the answer with the right code.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you sholud use StartCoroutine() method instead of just calling makenew(). Try this:

```
StartCoroutine(makenew());
```

Here's the link to the documentation:
[MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot of `StartCoroutine`

so try:

```
void OnTriggerEnter (Collider other){

if (other.gameObject.CompareTag ("cube1")) { 
    other.gameObject.SetActive (false);
    StartCoroutine (makenew ());

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Just to mention one thing - coroutines also stop if the GameObject gets disabled ([See this answer](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/34169/does-deactivating-a-gameobject-automatically-stop.html)). So you might need to use Invoke() instead:

```
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag ("cube1")) { 
        other.gameObject.SetActive (false);
        Invoke("makenew", 1f);

    }

}

void makenew ()
{
    GameObject cube = Instantiate (cubePrefab) as GameObject;
    gameObject.SetActive (true);
}
```

See [this quick tutorial of Invoke](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/scripting/invoke) if you need to better grasp what's going on.

Other answers are also useful, though.